# JavaScript event on addition of certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a page with list of URLs,

When User clicks on one of the URL, a JQuery Modal popup opens with list of elements. Items in the list are added dynamically by doing AJAX call.

Each Item in the list has Raty & timeago (both JQuery Plugins){"5 star rating, 2 Months Ago"}.

Now the problem is - Typically We execute JavaScript functions related to these plugins at the time of page load in Document.ready event.

However, Now these functions need to be executed After items are added & are ready for processing.

What is name of the event to handle?

Edit:-

Easier way to visualize is : When we add Comments to a any question on StackOverlow; we can see "added 5 minutes ago". This part of counting time & showing 'Time ago' is handled by 'Time Ago' Plugin. Certain function (timeago) must be executed on on addition of an element(Comment in case of StackOverflow). Now all I want to know is some handle to execute that function on addition of new element to Dom Tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation using jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.classname', function(){

});
```

#### Delegated events

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: I think he meant some function provided by the plugins must be executed on the elements added dynamically through ajax. Not delegation of events!

Comment: I followed the title "JavaScript event on addition of certain element"

Comment: Just for Clarification - The event which is fired afterthe element is added will contain list of function I would like to execute on addition of elements.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

If you know for sure that the parent to which links will be added dynamically will be present at DOM ready, you can do

```
$('#parent_container').on('click', '.className', function(){

})
```

Otherwise, you can attach to the document like this

```
 $(document).on('click', '.className', function(){

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple pattern.  No plugins required...

```
var _eventTimer;


function updateWithAjaxCall(){

    stopEvents();

    $.ajax({
        //...
    })
    .fail(){
        //...
        resumeEvents();
    }
    .done(){
        //...

                    // reset your time ago here...
        $("#time-ago").text(0);
        resumeEvents();
    };
}



function refreshTimeAgo(){

    stopEvents();

    // update your time ago here...
    $("#time-ago").text($("#time-ago").text + 1);

    resumeEvents();

}

function resumeEvents() {
    clearTimeout(_eventTimer);
    _eventTimer = setTimeout(function () { refreshTimeAgo() }, 60000);
}

function stopEvents() {
    clearTimeout(_eventTimer);

}
```